# Simple Query Running slowly in SQL Server?

Tags: sql, sql-server, entity-framework, sql-server-2012, entity-framework-6

I have only 2 tables, Products and Images. In Products I have only 50,000 rows and in Images I have 10 rows. I have wrote a very simple query that will give me top 10 products. Actually, this query generated by EF.

```
SELECT TOP (10) 
    [Join1].[Id1] AS [Id], 
    [Join1].[Name] AS [Name], 
    [Join1].[Price] AS [Price], 
    [Join1].[NewPrice] AS [NewPrice], 
    [Join1].[ShortDescription] AS [ShortDescription], 
    [Join1].[SKU] AS [SKU], 
    [Join1].[ProductTypeID] AS [ProductTypeID], 
    [Join1].[ImageID] AS [ImageID], 
    [Join1].[Promotion] AS [Promotion], 
    [Join1].[ParentID] AS [ParentID], 
    [Join1].[Attributes] AS [Attributes], 
    [Join1].[Id2] AS [Id1], 
    [Join1].[Path] AS [Path]
FROM (
   SELECT [Extent1].[Id] AS [Id1]
        , [Extent1].[Name] AS [Name]
        , [Extent1].[Price] AS [Price]
        , [Extent1].[NewPrice] AS [NewPrice]
        , [Extent1].[ShortDescription] AS [ShortDescription]
        , [Extent1].[SKU] AS [SKU]
        , [Extent1].[ProductTypeID] AS [ProductTypeID]
        , [Extent1].[ImageID] AS [ImageID]
        , [Extent1].[Promotion] AS [Promotion]
        , [Extent1].[ParentID] AS [ParentID]
        , [Extent1].[Attributes] AS [Attributes]
        , [Extent2].[Id] AS [Id2]
        , [Extent2].[Path] AS [Path]
        , row_number() OVER (ORDER BY [Extent1].[Id] ASC) AS [row_number]
   FROM  [dbo].[Products] AS [Extent1]
   INNER JOIN [dbo].[Images] AS [Extent2] ON [Extent1].[ImageID] = [Extent2].[Id]
)  AS [Join1]
WHERE [Join1].[row_number] > 0
ORDER BY [Join1].[Id1] ASC
```

But this query is taking 3 seconds. How can I improve this query performance. Id is primary key and identity column.

Comment: What is your code that you are writing which outputs this query?

Comment: @BiffBaffBoff: As follows from the tags, it must be Entity Framework 6 that generates this beast.

Comment: Yes, but show the code you are writing which generates this query.. Ie your LINQ code in your method

Comment: @BiffBaffBoff, the code is simple EF `products.include(p => p.Image)`

Comment: So you're returning 50000 products at once? And you're selecting every column from `Product` and `Image`? Why?

Comment: @BiffBaffBoff, I am thinking you are not aware of `TOP (10)`

Comment: Of course I am. But the code you posted `products.include(p => p.Image)` will select all. Please paste your code exactly how it is in your question.. as this could have a big effect to how EF is constructing your query..

Answer (score 0):

OK I have added JOIN later then it start working fast.

```
SELECT TOP (10)
    [Join1].[Id1] AS [Id],
    [Join1].[Name] AS [Name],
    [Join1].[Price] AS [Price],
    [Join1].[NewPrice] AS [NewPrice],
    [Join1].[ShortDescription] AS [ShortDescription],
    [Join1].[SKU] AS [SKU],
    [Join1].[ProductTypeID] AS [ProductTypeID],
    [Join1].[ImageID] AS [ImageID],
    [Join1].[Promotion] AS [Promotion],
    [Join1].[ParentID] AS [ParentID],
    [Join1].[Attributes] AS [Attributes],
    [Join2].[Id] AS [Id2],
    [Join2].[Path] AS [Path]
FROM (SELECT
    [Extent1].[Id] AS [Id1],
    [Extent1].[Name] AS [Name],
    [Extent1].[Price] AS [Price],
    [Extent1].[NewPrice] AS [NewPrice],
    [Extent1].[ShortDescription] AS [ShortDescription],
    [Extent1].[SKU] AS [SKU],
    [Extent1].[ProductTypeID] AS [ProductTypeID],
    [Extent1].[ImageID] AS [ImageID],
    [Extent1].[Promotion] AS [Promotion],
    [Extent1].[ParentID] AS [ParentID],
    [Extent1].[Attributes] AS [Attributes],
    ROW_NUMBER() OVER (ORDER BY [Extent1].[Id] ASC) AS [row_number]
FROM [dbo].[Products] AS [Extent1]) AS [Join1]
INNER JOIN [dbo].[Images] AS [Join2] ON [Join1].[ImageID] = [Join2].[Id]
WHERE [Join1].[row_number] > 0
ORDER BY [Join1].[Id1] ASC
```

But I don't understand why EF doing this stuff.

Comment: @ElectricLlama, are you sure? The same query is running in my sql management studio

Comment: Its probably taking quite a bit of time because of the Row number and the sorting and filtering that's applied to it. The Row number is a dynamic column that doesn't have any indexing on it. The database therefore has to do a lot of processing (accessing every row probably) to figure out which rows you want. You can check this on the execution plan by looking at the number of rows accessed (if this equals the number of rows on the table its doing all the hard work). The way to make it quicker is to find another way of sorting and filtering without row_number.

Comment: Sorry my mistake, I missed the closing bracket.